# how to create own function in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

how to create own function and call it another function? like-

```
$('.mycls li').hover(function() {    
var divid = $(this).find('li').attr('some_attr');
call myfunc(divid);
});

function myfunc(divid)
{
$(divid).show();
//I want to hide rest all divs 
$('div#info1').hide();
$('div#info2').hide();
$('div#info3').hide();
}
```

**I have 2 questions one is how to implement this logic in jquery second is which attribute can be used to reference the specific li to specific div**

my divs are as-

```
<div id="info1">
//some information
</div>
<div id="info2">
</div>
....
```

Comment: You have already answered your first question. As for the second... I don't understand, please clarify. I think you have to show more of your HTML markup.

Comment: @Kling I just want to call to myfunc() on mouseover of li items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your functions should be able to operate on the wrapped set like other methods/functions of jquery. Consider a plugin, it is easy:

[jQuery Plugin Tutorial](http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial)

Or see:

[Defining your own functions in jQuery](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/basil/archive/2008/09/22/defining-your-own-functions-in-jquery.aspx)

Comment: have a look on my code is it correct-  
    <script>
    $('.smenu li').mouseover( function(){
       myfunnc();
    });
    jQuery.fn.myfunc = function() {
     $('div#telcosinfo').show("medium");
    }
     </script>

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this:

```
jQuery.fn.doSomeStuff = function(options, callback) {
    var $elem = $(this[0]);
    var args = options || {};
    
    // doSomeStuff
    alert("DOM element: "+$elem.html());
    alert("this ia a parameter:"+ args.aParameter);
    
    if (typeof callback == 'function') { // make sure the callback is a function
        callback.call(this); // brings the scope to the callback
    }
    return $elem; //ensures jquery chainability
};
```

1. define your own function
2. specify parameters and callback
3. ensure jquery chainability

You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRcx6/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyword `call` that you need to use to call a function. So just using

```
myfunc(divid);
```

to call your function will do.

To link your `li`-s to your `div`-s you can use an id naming scheme, for instance, give all your `li`-s ids beginning with a d and all your `div` ids beginning with "info" as you have them, but have the bits after that be the same.

```
<li id='d1'> </li>
<li id='d2'> </li>
<li id='d3'> </li>

<div id='info1'></div>
<div id='info2'></div>
<div id='info3'></div>
```

and then use

```
$('.mycls li').hover(function() {      
    // get the number part of the li id and use it to
    // build the divid by appending it to "info"
    var divid = "info" + $(this).attr('id').slice(1);
    myfunc(divid);   
});   

function myfunc(divid)   
{
     $("#" + divid).show();   
     //hide all divs that do not have id=divid
     $("div:not(#" + divid + ")").hide();
}
```

Comment: it means `div`-s id must be like `1,2,3...?`

Comment: no, `div`-s ids must be like `info1,info2,info3` - I've updated my answer to make this clearer

Comment: ya I got it...but that is not working even when I am passing `var divid="info1"; myfunc(divid);` it is not calling the function but all `div`-s of the page are getting disappeared.